# IntelliJ aligning variables

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following code that I want to format:

```
public static final String s1 = "first", s2 = "second", s3 = "third";
```

into this

```
public static final String s1 = "first", 
                           s2 = "second", 
                           s3 = "third";
```

I tried selecting all the Group Declaration checkboxes but they didn't do quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid this. It conflicts with Java style conventions. Intellij doesn't provide this feature. You can use Ctrl+Alt+L for refactoring your code properly.